# Structure JS - Variable empty?

Tags: javascript

Iam a total JS Newb, and trying to structure my simple JS code a bit. Goal is to get users location.

It works, but the getUserCoordinates function does not return an value? I think it is just a logical failure from a beginner?

```
var app = {

geocoder: null,

init: function() {
    this.geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    coordinates = this.getUserCoordinates();
    console.log(coordinates); // empty??
    return;
},

getUserCoordinates: function() {

    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition( 

            function (coords) { 
                console.log(coords); // works Geocoder Object!
                return coords; // the problem 
            }, // more code
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's a quite common error for beginners. The `getCurrentPosition` method is asynchronous (it takes some time to determine the location) and does return nothing. When finished, it will invoke the `callback` function you passed into it - somewhen in the future. The value is only available inside that callback, or to functions that are called from there.

Comment: Thanks sounds logical, is there any nice solution for this?

Comment: You can use callback function (which you pass into your `getUserCoordinates` methods), or you return a [Promise](http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/Promises) from the function that represents the value and uses callbacks internally.